# Throw string exception from inherited exception class

Tags: c++, exception, throw, object-slicing

I implemented my exception `class` which inherited from `std::exception` like the following :

```
class MyException : public exception
{
public:
    MyException(string exc)
    {
        this->exc = exc;
    }

    const char * what() const throw ()
    {
        return exc.c_str();
    }

private:
    string exc;
};
```

Now i throw `MyException` manually and suppose that an exception occurred in my `code`, But i tested it in two different ways in `catch` section :

1. **Catch normally** *`catch (const std::exception exc)`*

   ```
   try
   {
       throw MyException("This is an exception");
   }
       catch (const std::exception exc)
   {
       MessageBoxA(NULL, exc.what(), "", MB_OK);
   }
   ```
2. **Catch with reference** *`catch (const std::exception &exc)`*

   ```
   try
   {
       throw MyException("This is an exception");
   }
       catch (const std::exception &exc)
   {
       MessageBoxA(NULL, exc.what(), "", MB_OK);
   }
   ```

The first thrown exception string is :

> ```
> Unknown exception
> ```

And the second thrown exception (The one that has `&` in catch section) is :

> ```
> This is an exception
> ```

Why can't i get my custom exception *string* while using catch normally without reference(`&`) and why is it ***OK*** by reference?

Comment: Only catch exceptions by const ref. Otherwise you will encounter object slicing.

Comment: @AndyG What do you mean by `object slicing`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: @AndyG If your comment posted as an answer, then it was the best answer....

Comment: @AndyG Thanks in advance...

Comment: Done. I added a few more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

This happens when a derived instance is received by *value* as its base class -- In your case, catching `std::exception` by value. Your derived class' member is "sliced off" in the process of conversion to the base class.

Receiving by pointer or by (const) reference is always preferable when you expect to use a parameter polymorphically. For catching a `std::exception` you should always catch by const reference (I can't really think of a scenario where you *wouldn't*).

Comment: The best sentence : `This happens when a derived instance is received by value as its base class -- In your case, catching std::exception by value`

Answer (score 1):

You are catching an `std::exception` by value, your compiler calls the copy ctor of `std::exception` and your data is lost.

Either;

1. Catch your exception by reference, which doesn't result in copying.
   or
2. Catch `MyException` directly.

Option 2 still performs a copy, which is redundant, so I'd go with option 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limit that all of polymorphism has, not just the exceptions.

When you catch by reference, you catch a reference to an existing instance of the derived class, and as such, you can call their virtual methods.

When you catch by value (which you should never do, this being one of the reasons), you catch an `std::exception` object as itself. Because `exception` is not abstract, this will, of course, work. However, you are now given a new object whose type is `std::exception`. As such, it never had a `exc` member, and more importantly, it does not have the `what` override that you want. Instead, the original definition of `what` is called, which - because you never initialized the base exception - prints `"Unknown exception"`.